# Spinner is not working with horizontal listview

Tags: android

I am new in android. I would like to special thank in advance.
The problem is, I am using horizontal list view and use spinner inside of horizontal list view adapter. it showing right but when we click on spinner then onItemSelected listener is not invoke.

below code is inside of adapter class which is implemened BaseAdapter

```
spinerConfigurableList=(Spinner) row.findViewById(R.id.spinerConfigurableList);
spinerConfigurableList.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                   // spinerConfigurableList.setSelection(position);
                    configurableSelection=position;//Problem is here,this never invoke.

                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });

I am following this example https://github.com/MeetMe/Android-HorizontalListView

    Xml for adapter.
     <LinearLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/llDrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"

            >
            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinerConfigurableList"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                android:paddingRight="0dp"
                android:prompt="@string/app_name"
                android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:theme="@style/AppThemeForSpinner"
                android:textColor="@color/font_color_black_light"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_level_two"
                ></Spinner>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
        // your code here
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
        // your code here
    }
});
```

Use this instead.

Comment: Hi Zach Bullil ,I am using same but there are little bit difference ,You are using new OnItemSelectedListener() { override method  } ,but i am using new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){ override method } however i try to use new OnItemSelectedListener() but it is not found.when we enter ALT+ENTER to import class then it has been changed like new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(),Please explain how to use this